# hamcrest TypeSafeMatcher fails matching of double array

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest

I wrote this matcher to check the contents of a `double[]`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static Matcher<double[]> isArrayCloseTo(double[] expected) {
    final double DELTA = 1e-10;
    List<Matcher<Double>> matchers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double d : expected)
        matchers.add(new IsCloseTo(d, DELTA));
    return new IsArray(matchers.toArray(new Matcher[matchers.size()]));
}
```

I suppress those warnings because there's nothing I can do about an array not having a generic type. The method looks fine, but it always fails:

```
assertThat(new double[] { .1 }, isArrayCloseTo(new double[] { .1 })); //fails
```

The problem is in [TypesafeMatcher, line 65](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.java#65): `expectedType.isInstance(item)`, where `expectedType` is `Object.class` and `item` is `[0.1]`.

I suspect that this problem has to do with the fact that I can't genericize the `Matcher`s array I pass to `IsArray`, but I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone tell me how I should be matching an array of doubles?

Comment: Can you post the assertion failure stacktrace? It looks like the problem is with your use of primitive `double` on the `expected` and `Matcher`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ultimately goes back to the fact that `double[]` cannot be cast to `Double[]`, and the same goes for `Matcher<double[]>` to `Matcher<Double[]>`.

If you can change all your uses of primitive `double[]` to `Double[]`, then your approach works fine. Otherwise, you'll need to write your own custom matcher. I've included below a custom Matcher that builds on your code.

This is essentially a duplicate of this:
[How can I use Hamcrest to check if each element in an array of doubles is "close" to each element in another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623458/how-can-i-use-hamcrest-to-check-if-each-element-in-an-array-of-doubles-is-close)

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public static Matcher<double[]> isArrayCloseTo(double[] expected) {
    final double DELTA = 1e-10;
    List<Matcher<Double>> matchers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double d : expected)
        matchers.add(new IsCloseTo(d, DELTA));

    return new CustomTypeSafeMatcher<double[]>("array that is close to" + Arrays.toString(expected)) {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(double[] actual) {
            return new IsArray<Double>(matchers.toArray(new Matcher[matchers.size()]))
                    .matchesSafely(Arrays.stream(actual).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new));
        }
    };
}
```