# How to translate assertArrayEquals(,,) to new style?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit4, hamcrest

When I have:

```
double[] array1 = ..., array2 = ...;
assertArrayEquals(array1, array2, 1e-10);
```

I get a warning from IntelliJ stating that:

> Assert expression 'assertArrayEquals(array1, array2, 1e-10);' can be replaced with 'assertThat' call
>
> [this inspection] Reports usages of **Assert.assertEquals**, **Assert.assertTrue** etc. methods when its can be migrated to **Assert.assertThat**

I've tried to find a matcher that goes together with `assertThat` and can handle floating-point round-off errors. I've found nothing in the content assistant, and I found [on the internet](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/IsCloseTo.html) that I could use

```
assertThat(array2, is(org.hamcrest.number.IsCloseTo.closeTo(array1, 1e-10)));
```

However, I get an error that package `org.hamcrest.number` is not found. And sure enough, `hamcrest` has only two subpackages, `core` and `internal`. It turns out, IntelliJ **only** ships the hamcrest-core jar, not the other hamcrest jars.

If IntelliJ tells me that my code *can* be migrated to `assertThat`, shouldn't there be code available capable of doing so? Is this [warning message] an IntelliJ bug?

My main question is, how do I migrate this statement like IntelliJ wants me to?

---

[edit] In retrospect, `org.hamcrest.number.IsCloseTo` doesn't even handle arrays, so this gets even more puzzling.

Comment: Are you using the JUnit refactoring plugin? It's third party. It probably assumes that you have the full set of hamcrest libs.

Comment: In [Truth](http://google.github.io/truth/) this'd be [`assertThat(array2).usingTolerance(1e-10).containsExactly(array1).inOrder()`](http://google.github.io/truth/api/latest/com/google/common/truth/PrimitiveDoubleArraySubject.html#usingTolerance(double)). As you noticed, you can't use `IsCloseTo` since it doesn't apply to arrays. Looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10623458/113632) I'd guess Hamcrest doesn't support "close to" assertions on arrays/iterables.

Comment: @teppic No third party plugins, just IDEA Community edition out of the box.